# Amazonlinux2023 install hardended version of pip for python

Tags: python, pip, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2023

I want to sue `amazonlinux2023` with as few "un-hardened" packages as possible.

[AL2023 ships with `python`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/python.html) but not `pip`

So what is the correct way to get a "hardened" version of `pip` corresponding to the python package that's shipped?

Is  `python3 -m ensurepip` sufficient?

thanks

Comment: What would be a hardened version of `pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Amazon Linux 2023 packages list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-AL2023.2.html) lists a package called `python3-pip`.

If you want to stay on the narrow supported path, I'd just go and install that.